# Excel/VBA send email with hyperlink and variable cell value

Tags: excel, vba, email, if-statement, hyperlink

I have set up a standard module in workbook to send me an email. I am now stuck on two portions.

1. I would like in the email to have the text "check list" by hyperlinked to http://"linktospreadsheet".html.
2. The expiration date in the email text needs to be a variable value, dependent on a value within the linked spreadsheet.

Also, can someone provide a guide on how to execute this module when the items expiration date is actually approaching? Below is the code:

```
Option Explicit

  Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "A plan is now # days from expiring" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Please view the check list for details." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "http://linktospreadsheet.html"
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "name@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Subject"
        .Body = strbody
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three main way for customizing the message body.

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) - doesn't allows to add hyperlinks, only a raw text is acceptable.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - HTML markup can be used to customize the body.
3. Word editor - the Word object model can be used to customize the body. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property returns an instance of the Word document which represents the message body.

As you may see, you can use the #2 or #3 option to get the job done.

You can read more about these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article in MSDN.

> 1.I would like in the email to have the text "check list" by hyperlinked to http://"linktospreadsheet".html

You can add hyperlink using the HTML markup (`<a href="web_address_here"/>`) or by using the Word object model (see `Hyperlinks.Add`).

> 2.The expiration date in the email text needs to be a variable value, dependent on a value within the linked spreadsheet.

You can add any information at runtime to the message body. Please refer to the #2 and #3 options described above.